# Create page for $_GET request

Tags: php

I'm developing a system for real estate agents, and it's doing fine until now. The problem is in the product page.

I've managed to show the products using GET requests. Perhaps, I want to have "real" page links, that doesn't look like some filters. (for example, this is what I want: https://www.berteimoveis.com.br/imovel/BT7261/apartamento-1-dormitorios-no-bairro-jardim-carvalho-em-porto-alegre/). In this case, there is no folder called "BT7261" in the system, I suppose it just display it there, but use it to query an SQL, like I'm doing. This were developed on CodeIgniter.

Now, some code. This is what i'm doing and it's fine:

> http://localhost/imoveisextraordinarios/premium/imovel/index.php?imovel=lancamento&id=20

In this example, I'm passing the property type as "imovel" and the id number, which I use to query on the index and it works fine. For reference:

```
if ($_GET['imovel'] == 'avulso') {  // code here, parse the property with the same ID }
```

Using the first example, I would like to do something like this:

> http://localhost/imoveisextraordinarios/premium/imovel/avulso/1016/Casa+gen%C3%A9rica+1/

So, how could i do it, without having to create a folder for each property? I need to think on it, because i'll integrate with an external API soon, and there's lots of products there. Also, i'll need to create a dynamic sitemap with Cron Jobs later.

For reference, my code was built mostly on hand, only using some front-end templates.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. I wanted to know about PHP routes, but i didn't knew where to start. Also, i recommend this to anyone trying to do this without framework: https://github.com/akay25/route.

Comment: Downvotes are just messages, and are not insults. It would be helpful if people were to offer advice when they downvote, but they are not obligated to. Voting is anonymous by design.

Comment: At a guess, the downvotes were for the chatty material and/or the case errors. One of the things that surprises people here is that posts (both questions and answers) are much more like documentation than a traditional forum. Thus, we want them to be preceded by solid research effort, and we want them to be presented in a clear and readable fashion.